# Regex exclude rows in csv that has forbidding word

Tags: python, regex

I've been trying to exclude all the rows that contain 'shirt' and then from that have the rows that have 'cotton' (case insensitive)
for example:
"Cotton Shirt for sale" - don't include
"Cotton Dress for Sale" - Pass
"dress shirt-V-neck-cotton" -fail
"no words relevant" - Fail (no cotton in it)
"cotton-url click" - pass
My regex:

```
pattern = re.compile('(?i)^((?!.*shirt).).*(?=.*cotton.*)')
```

But for some reason my rows in csv still remain on a sentence:
"Stone Italian Yarn Fringe Yoke Cable Cotton Shirt New Look"
my code:

```
pattern1 = re.compile("(?i)(.*shirt.*)")
    with open("sample.csv", 'r', encoding="utf-8") as bigCSV:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(bigCSV)
        counterWithout = 0
        counterCheck = 0
        headFlag = True
        for row in csv_reader:
            if headFlag:
                header = row
                headFlag = False
            if any(pattern.match(line) for line in row)://there is a difference in the number of rows here
                if any(pattern1.match(line) for line in row):
                    print(row)
                    counterCheck += 1
                counterWithout += 1
```

Help fix regex please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Options:

1. Define two regex patterns (# Solution 1)
2. Use `re.findall` (# Solution 2)
3. Search 'shirt' behind and ahead of 'cotton' (# Solution 3)
4. Check strings without regex (# Solution 4)

### Code:

#### # Preparation:

```py
import re

test_strings = [
    'Cotton Shirt for sale',
    'Cotton Dress for Sale', # Pass
    'dress shirt-V-neck-cotton',
    'no words relevant',
    'cotton-url click', # Pass
    'Stone Italian Yarn Fringe Yoke Cable Cotton Shirt New Look',
    'Black Chunky Cotton Round Neck Shirt',
    ]
```

#### # Solution 1:

```py
pat_cotton = re.compile(r'cotton', re.IGNORECASE)
pat_shirt = re.compile(r'shirt', re.IGNORECASE)

for s in test_strings:
    if pat_cotton.search(s) and not pat_shirt.search(s):
        print(s)
```

#### # Solution 2:

```py
pat = re.compile(r'shirt|cotton', re.IGNORECASE)

for s in test_strings:
    elements = set(e.lower() for e in pat.findall(s))
    if 'cotton' in elements and len(elements) == 1:
        print(s)
```

#### # Solution 3:

```py
pat = re.compile(r'.*(?:(shirt)|^).*?cotton.*?(?:(shirt)|$)', re.IGNORECASE)

for s in test_strings:
    m = pat.search(s)
    if m and m.group(1) is None and m.group(2) is None:
        print(s)
```

#### # Solution 4:

```py
for s in test_strings:
    s_lower = s.lower()
    if s_lower.find('cotton') >= 0 and s_lower.find('shirt') < 0:
        print(s)
```

### Output:

```
Cotton Dress for Sale
cotton-url click
```

Comment: I had hoped to find a single one, so I would cut the other search but yeah, this works too

Comment: I updated my answer several times and now 4 options are available.

Answer (score 1):

Would you consider pandas? After you load in your csv file with `pd.read_csv(...)`, you'll presumably get a DataFrame that will look, at a minimum, something like the below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "description":["Cotton Shirt for sale",
                    "Cotton Dress for Sale",
                    "dress shirt-V-neck-cotton",
                    "no words relevant",
                    "cotton-url click"]
})
```

Then:

```
# First step: add a column to keep track of what we're including/excluding. Can set directly to False; see later.
df["include"] = "-" 

# Mark every row containing "shirt", case insensitive, as not to include.
df.loc[df["description"].str.contains("shirt", case=False), "include"] = False

# Of the rows that are left, mark as True if they contain "cotton".
df.loc[
    (df["include"]=="-") &
    (df["description"].str.contains("cotton", case=False)), "include"
]=True
```

At this point the DataFrame looks like this:

[image]

You can now set any remaining rows marked `-` to `False` (I find it easier to debug this way, especially if the conditions get more complicated), or you could have started off by initialising the `"include"` column to `False`.

Comment: Personally I agree, but I was told to find a way to make it work using regex

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.*(cotton)?.*shirt.*|.*shirt.*(cotton)?.*`
It will match every shirt with condition of cotton before or after it. So you can delete every row that satisfy this.

[example](https://regex101.com/r/LdT8PH/1)

```
import re
import csv

header = ['name', 'val', 'test']
data = [
    ["Cotton Dress for Sale", 1, 'test1'],
    ["dress shirt-V-neck-cotton", 2, 'test2'],
    ["no words relevant", 3, 'test3'],
    ["Cotton Shirt for sale", 4, 'test4'],
    ["Stone Italian Yarn Fringe Yoke Cable Cotton Shirt New Look", 5, 'test5'],
    ["cotton-url click", 6, 'test6'],
]

# with open('test.csv', 'w', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
#     writer = csv.writer(f)

#     # write the header
#     writer.writerow(header)

#     # write multiple rows
#     writer.writerows(data)


regex = re.compile(r'.*(cotton)?.*shirt.*|.*shirt.*(cotton)?.*',
                   re.IGNORECASE)
with open('test.csv', 'r', encoding='UTF8', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    headFlag = True
    counterWithout = 0
    counterCheck = 0
    for row in reader:
        if headFlag:
            header = row
            headFlag = False
        else:
            if not any(regex.match(x) for x in row):
                counterCheck += 1
                print(row)
            else:
                counterWithout += 1
    print(f'{counterCheck=}, {counterWithout=}')
```

Comment: The problem is not even that much with the regex, the problem is in the code logic here.

Comment: I deleted more rows than it should, I should have 91 rows but now I have 78

Comment: could you post your csv file?

Comment: @Yuki1112 this should  work on given examples, maybe check if any other row can be matched that could change results

Comment: Black Chunky Cotton Round Neck Shirt- It matched and put in row even through 'shirt' is there